# Exercise of Lie subalgebra

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $e_1,\ldots,e_{2n}$ a canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and consider  $E=Span(e_1,\ldots,e_{n})$. $O(2n)$ is the orthogonal group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{o}(2n)$. Define 
$$C=\{A\in GL(2n;\mathbb{R})| A(E)\subset E\}.$$

(A) Prove that $C$ is a closed subgroup of $GL(2n;\mathbb{R})$.

(B) Let $\mathfrak{c}=Lie(C)$. Show that $\mathfrak{c}=\{X\in M(2n;\mathbb{R})|X(E)\subset E\}$.

(C) Show that $\mathfrak{o}(2n)+\mathfrak{c}=M(2n;\mathbb{R})$.

(D) Deduz that the map 
$$O(2n)\times C \to GL(2n;\mathbb{R}), \quad(B,A)\mapsto BA^{-1}$$
has surjective derivative at $(I,I)$.

Here is what I've done:

(B) $\mathfrak{c}=\{X\in \mathfrak{gl}(2n;\mathbb{R})|\forall t\in \mathbb{R},\exp(tX)\in C\}$ and let 
$$V=\{X\in M(2n;\mathbb{R})|X(E)\subset E\}$$
We have to prove that $V=\mathfrak{c}$.

**1)** $V\subset \mathfrak{c}$
Let $X\in V$, i.e. $X(E)\subset E$, let us prove that $\exp(tX)in C$, for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$

$$\exp(tX)=I+tX+\dfrac{t^2}{2}X^2+\dfrac{t^3}{6}X^3+\cdots$$
then

$$\exp(tX)(E)=I(E)+(tX)(E)+\left(\dfrac{t^2}{2}X^2\right)(E)+\left(\dfrac{t^3}{6}X^3\right)(E)+\cdots$$

$$\exp(tX)(E)=E+t(X(E))+\left(\dfrac{t^2}{2}\right)X^2(E)+\left(\dfrac{t^3}{6}\right)X^3(E)+\cdots.........(*)$$

Since $X(E)\subset E$, then $X^n(E)\subset E$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, then in (*) we get
$$\exp(tX)(E)\subset E,\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow \exp(tX)\in C, \forall t\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Therefore $X\in \mathfrak{c}$, i.e. $V\subset \mathfrak{c}$.

**2)** $\mathfrak{c}\subset V$
Let $X\in \mathfrak{c}$, then $\exp(tX)\in C, \forall t\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\exp(tX)(E)\subset E$, then $\gamma_X(t)(E)\subset E$, for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

$$\gamma_X(t)(e_k)=a_1(t)e_1+...+a_n(t)e_n$$
then 
$$\gamma'_X(0)(e_k)=a_1'(0)e_1+...+a_n'(0)e_n\Rightarrow X(e_k)a_1'(0)e_1+...+a_n'(0)e_n\in E$$
which gives
$$X(E)\subset E,$$
then $X\in V$, i.e, $\mathfrak{c}\subset V$.

From **1)** e **2)** we get $\mathfrak{c}=V$

(C) If $X\in\mathfrak{c}$, then $X(E)\subset E$, it means, that the subspace $E$ is $X-$invariant, and I think that I have to use some property of invariant subspaces, is it right?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) $C$ is closed because the elements of $C$ are those invertible matrices $(a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant2n}$ such that $a_{ij}=0$ when $i>n$ and $j\leqslant n$.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To attack (C), write out $2n\times 2n$-matrices in block form with blocks of sizes $n$. It is then easy to explicitly describe $\mathfrak c$ and $\mathfrak o(2n)$ and to deduce the result.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much