# Derivative of the product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, differential-geometry, lie-groups, matrix-calculus

please give me a hint for the following exercise: It is the third part of this exercise

[Complementar Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{o}(2n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513322/complementar-lie-subalgebra-of-mathfrako2n/2514822#2514822)

Let $O(n)$ be the real orthogonal group and define the map
$$F:O(n)\times GL(n;\mathbb{R})\to GL(n;\mathbb{R})$$
given by $(M,N)\longmapsto MN^{-1}$. Find $D_{(I,I)}F$.

---

I see that $$F(M,N)=m(M,i(N)),$$ where $m$ is the multiplication of matrices and $i$ the invertion. Also I know that

$D_{(I,I)}m(A,B)=A+B$ and $D_Ii=-I_d$

How can I continue? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have all you need to deduce from the chain rule that$$DF_{(e,e)}(M,N)=M+(-N)=M-N.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not sure of that, i got confused with the chain rule.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Done, I did not know that I had to do it, sorry for that.

Comment: @Miguemate It took me some time too.